# How can i set text type of my textview asterisk or bullet programatically in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-inputtype

i want to set my `textview's` `inputtype`to be asterisk or in bullet shape. i can set this property using `XML file(layout)`. but when i want to set this programatically it does not work. I use `textview1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);` but it show the string that i passed to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in the original documentation. You need two values since it manage bit definitions:

- http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/InputType.html

  textview1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType. TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Comment: You're welcome. if you agree, please mark it as resolved answer.

Comment: friend how can i set it to show normal text when it is in bullet shape?

Comment: Try with:
textview1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType. TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
or 
textview1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType. TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);